# Question on econometric specifications transformation

Tags: regression, misspecification

Two groups of forecasters are trying to forecast outcome variable y by issuing forecast X. Denote the two groups of forecasters with Z={1,2}. We want to know whether group 1 is more accurate in forecasting the outcome variable than group 2.

Approach 1: Regress the outcome variable on the forecasts, plus an interaction with an indicator for the analyst group (Z):
y= α+βX+δ(X×Z)+γZ

If δ>0, then the forecasts by analysts from group 2 are more accurate.

Approach 2: Regress the product of the forecast and the outcome variable on an indicator for the analyst group (Z):
y×X= μ+θZ

If θ>0, then the forecasts by analysts from group 2 are more accurate.
Why are these two approaches not equivalent?

Comment: It's hard to see how either approach addresses the problem.  The first issue you need to confront is how to quantify accuracy.  What do you have in mind?  What kind of variables are $y$ and $X$ and how do you measure the accuracy of $X$ relative to $y$?